# Mostrar y ocultar opciones del select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Navegando encontré una manera para ocultar una `option` de varios `select` dependiendo de la `id`, eso me ayudó mucho.

Lo que estoy intentado de hacer es que al cambiar la `option` esta vuelva a ser visible en todos los `select` para poder seleccionarla.

No es nada del otro mundo, son 9 `select` con las mismas opciones y 2 de ellos tienen la misma `id` para el ejemplo.

```js
$(document).on('change','.sel',function(){
//aqui oculta la option de los demas select
 $('#one select').siblings().find('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').hide();

});

$(document).ready ( function(){
//esta es una prueba para ocultar una option al cargar, no es importante 
  var id = 1;
  $('#one select').siblings().find('option[value="'+id+'"]').hide();


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="one">
    <td>
      <select class="sel">
  <option>Selecciona</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Tow</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Ford</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="6">Six</option>
  <option value="7">Seven</option>
  <option value="8">echt</option>
  <option value="9">nine</option>
  <option value="10">then</option> 
</select>
<select class="sel">
  <option>Selecciona</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Tow</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Ford</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="6">Six</option>
  <option value="7">Seven</option>
  <option value="8">echt</option>
  <option value="9">nine</option>
  <option value="10">then</option> 
</select>
<select class="sel">
  <option>Selecciona</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Tow</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Ford</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="6">Six</option>
  <option value="7">Seven</option>
  <option value="8">echt</option>
  <option value="9">nine</option>
  <option value="10">then</option> 
</select>
    </td>
  </tr>  
  <tr id="one">
    <td>
      <select class="sel">
  <option>Selecciona</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Tow</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Ford</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="6">Six</option>
  <option value="7">Seven</option>
  <option value="8">echt</option>
  <option value="9">nine</option>
  <option value="10">then</option> 
</select>
<select class="sel">
  <option>Selecciona</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Tow</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Ford</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="6">Six</option>
  <option value="7">Seven</option>
  <option value="8">echt</option>
  <option value="9">nine</option>
  <option value="10">then</option> 
</select>
<select class="sel">
  <option>Selecciona</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Tow</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Ford</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="6">Six</option>
  <option value="7">Seven</option>
  <option value="8">echt</option>
  <option value="9">nine</option>
  <option value="10">then</option> 
</select>
    </td>
  </tr>
    <tr id="dos">
    <td>
      <select class="sel">
  <option>Selecciona</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Tow</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Ford</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="6">Six</option>
  <option value="7">Seven</option>
  <option value="8">echt</option>
  <option value="9">nine</option>
  <option value="10">then</option> 
</select>
<select class="sel">
  <option>Selecciona</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Tow</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Ford</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="6">Six</option>
  <option value="7">Seven</option>
  <option value="8">echt</option>
  <option value="9">nine</option>
  <option value="10">then</option> 
</select>
<select class="sel">
  <option>Selecciona</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Tow</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Ford</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="6">Six</option>
  <option value="7">Seven</option>
  <option value="8">echt</option>
  <option value="9">nine</option>
  <option value="10">then</option> 
</select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Evita el uso de repetir las ids, esta es una manera de identificar a algo unico digamos. Si quieres ampliar la selección deberias usar clases.

Comment: Entendido... Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intentando seguir un poco tu código.

1. La funcion [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) lo que hace es llamar a `cambiar`.
2. La funcion `cambiar` se encarga de revisar todos los `select` y guardar sus opciones seleccionadas en un array, en la misma posición que tiene su valor medainte [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/). He aprovechado que tienes como valores números.
3. Antes de guardar los casteo con [parseInt](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) para poder manejarlos mejor.
4. Despues recorro el array y comparo sus valores con `undefined`. De esta forma, se si ese valor esta seleccionado en alguna opcion o no.
5. Por último, si el valor es `undefined` saco la posicion de ese valor en el `array` siendo este el número a mostrar.

No se si me he explicado bien, dale una vuelta y me dices :)

He corregido errores ortográficos.
Evita repetir las `ids`, son identificadores únicos.

```js
$(".sel").change(function(){cambiar();});

function cambiar(){
  var array = [];
  $(".sel :selected").each(function(){
    array[$(this).val()]=(parseInt($(this).val()));
  });
  for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
   if(array[i]!=undefined){
      $(".sel option[value=" + array[i] + "]").hide();
    }
    if(array[i]==undefined){
      $(".sel option[value=" + i + "]").show();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="uno">
    <td>
      <select class="sel">
        <option value="0">Selecciona</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4">Four</option>
        <option value="5">Five</option>
        <option value="6">Six</option>
        <option value="7">Seven</option>
        <option value="8">Eight</option>
        <option value="9">Nine</option>
        <option value="10">Ten</option> 
      </select>
      <select class="sel">
        <option value="0">Selecciona</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4">Four</option>
        <option value="5">Five</option>
        <option value="6">Six</option>
        <option value="7">Seven</option>
        <option value="8">Eight</option>
        <option value="9">Nine</option>
        <option value="10">Ten</option>
      </select>
      <select class="sel">
        <option value="0">Selecciona</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4">Four</option>
        <option value="5">Five</option>
        <option value="6">Six</option>
        <option value="7">Seven</option>
        <option value="8">Eight</option>
        <option value="9">Nine</option>
        <option value="10">Ten</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>  
  <tr id="dos">
    <td>
      <select class="sel">
        <option value="0">Selecciona</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4">Four</option>
        <option value="5">Five</option>
        <option value="6">Six</option>
        <option value="7">Seven</option>
        <option value="8">Eight</option>
        <option value="9">Nine</option>
        <option value="10">Ten</option>
      </select>
      <select class="sel">
        <option value="0">Selecciona</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4">Four</option>
        <option value="5">Five</option>
        <option value="6">Six</option>
        <option value="7">Seven</option>
        <option value="8">Eight</option>
        <option value="9">Nine</option>
        <option value="10">Ten</option>
      </select>
      <select class="sel">
        <option value="0">Selecciona</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4">Four</option>
        <option value="5">Five</option>
        <option value="6">Six</option>
        <option value="7">Seven</option>
        <option value="8">Eight</option>
        <option value="9">Nine</option>
        <option value="10">Ten</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
    <tr id="tres">
    <td>
      <select class="sel">
        <option value="0">Selecciona</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4">Four</option>
        <option value="5">Five</option>
        <option value="6">Six</option>
        <option value="7">Seven</option>
        <option value="8">Eight</option>
        <option value="9">Nine</option>
        <option value="10">Ten</option>
      </select>
      <select class="sel">
        <option value="0">Selecciona</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4">Four</option>
        <option value="5">Five</option>
        <option value="6">Six</option>
        <option value="7">Seven</option>
        <option value="8">Eight</option>
        <option value="9">Nine</option>
        <option value="10">Ten</option>
      </select>
      <select class="sel">
        <option value="0">Selecciona</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4">Four</option>
        <option value="5">Five</option>
        <option value="6">Six</option>
        <option value="7">Seven</option>
        <option value="8">Eight</option>
        <option value="9">Nine</option>
        <option value="10">Ten</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Tu ejemplo me quedo claro, y gracias por corregir los errores gramaticales.

Answer (score 0):

Mira a ver si esto te sirve

```js
$(document).on('change','.sel',function(){
var selecteds='|'
//Recorremos todos los select y vemos que opcion esta marcada en cada uno
//y los concatenamos en un string para su posterior busqueda.
selecteds+=$('#one select').map(function(){
   if($(this).val().indexOf('Selecciona')==-1){
    return $(this).val();
   }
})
.get()
.join('|');

selecteds+='|';

//Recorremos todos los options
$('#one select').siblings().find('option').each(function(i,e){
  //Si el valor del option a comprobar no esta seleccionado en ninguno otro...
  if(selecteds.indexOf('|'+$(e).val()+'|')==-1){
    //Lo mostramos
    $(this).show();
  }
});
//aqui oculta la option de los demas select
$('#one select').siblings().find('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="one">
    <td>
      <select class="sel">
  <option>Selecciona</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Tow</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Ford</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="6">Six</option>
  <option value="7">Seven</option>
  <option value="8">echt</option>
  <option value="9">nine</option>
  <option value="10">then</option> 
</select>
<select class="sel">
  <option>Selecciona</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Tow</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Ford</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="6">Six</option>
  <option value="7">Seven</option>
  <option value="8">echt</option>
  <option value="9">nine</option>
  <option value="10">then</option> 
</select>
<select class="sel">
  <option>Selecciona</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Tow</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Ford</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="6">Six</option>
  <option value="7">Seven</option>
  <option value="8">echt</option>
  <option value="9">nine</option>
  <option value="10">then</option> 
</select>
    </td>
  </tr>  
  <tr id="one">
    <td>
      <select class="sel">
  <option>Selecciona</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Tow</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Ford</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="6">Six</option>
  <option value="7">Seven</option>
  <option value="8">echt</option>
  <option value="9">nine</option>
  <option value="10">then</option> 
</select>
<select class="sel">
  <option>Selecciona</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Tow</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Ford</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="6">Six</option>
  <option value="7">Seven</option>
  <option value="8">echt</option>
  <option value="9">nine</option>
  <option value="10">then</option> 
</select>
<select class="sel">
  <option>Selecciona</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Tow</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Ford</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="6">Six</option>
  <option value="7">Seven</option>
  <option value="8">echt</option>
  <option value="9">nine</option>
  <option value="10">then</option> 
</select>
    </td>
  </tr>
    <tr id="dos">
    <td>
      <select class="sel">
  <option>Selecciona</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Tow</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Ford</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="6">Six</option>
  <option value="7">Seven</option>
  <option value="8">echt</option>
  <option value="9">nine</option>
  <option value="10">then</option> 
</select>
<select class="sel">
  <option>Selecciona</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Tow</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Ford</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="6">Six</option>
  <option value="7">Seven</option>
  <option value="8">echt</option>
  <option value="9">nine</option>
  <option value="10">then</option> 
</select>
<select class="sel">
  <option>Selecciona</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Tow</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Ford</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="6">Six</option>
  <option value="7">Seven</option>
  <option value="8">echt</option>
  <option value="9">nine</option>
  <option value="10">then</option> 
</select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias funciono a la prefeccion...

Comment: Me alegro, para eso estamos ;)